# How to prevent a user from Editing Word document loaded in DsoFramer using C#4.0?

Tags: ms-word, dsoframer

We are developing C#.net 4.0 Windows Forms based application.we are using Dsoframer control to embed the Word document into my Application.Here, i want to prevent the user to edit the document.I have already opened Word Document in READ Only Mode.But still user can able to edit the doucment.Anyway, the updated content is not refelected in the original Document.But i would also like to prevent the user to make such editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 wordDoc.Protect(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading);
```

This is do that...